# Accessing Microsoft Dynamics 365 - API

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to access Microsoft Dynamics 365 online.
It is the first time I am working with this tool.

I want to access this through API.

I have gone through the following links :

[Link 1](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/alexanderdevelopment/archive/2016/11/27/dynamics-365-and-python-integration-using-the-web-api)

[Link 2](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/jasonlattimersblog/archive/2015/11/25/crm-web-api-using-python)

It shows that **AUTHORIZATION_URL** or **clientid** or **tokenendpoint**
are needed.

I have a simple MSD 365, I only have username and password with me.
So I am not able to understand how to connect to MSD 365.

My simple question is, is it possible to access/connect using username and password?

Or is it mandatory to have all these details?

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to use Dynamics CRM 365 web api inside CRM context like Javascript web resource then no need.

If planning to use it in any external app (developed using nodejs, python) then need to register App in Azure AD to get App client Id and get login token for accessing web api.

Second link example uses adal.js to get token directly using username & password without clientid.